# iOS: UIButton text doesn't immediately change if you long press then release it

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton

I'm targeting iOS 5.1 and using a storyboard. I have a UIButton within a UITableViewCell that, when tapped, calls the "Touch Up Inside" method, calls a web service, then within a completion handler, updates the UIButton's text with a call to a function that sets the text for all button states like so:

```
+(void) setButtonText:(NSString *)text forButton:(UIButton *)button
{
    [button setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    [button setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [button setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateSelected];
}
```

It works great if you just tap the button, but if you long press it then release, the web service call and completion handler get called and return immediately, but then it takes about 5 seconds before the text updates on the button. I have tried calling setNeedsDisplay on both the button and self.view. Any ideas how I can get the text to update immediately when someone does a long press+release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. I was setting the button text within the completionHandler, which runs a separate thread from the UI thread. Hence the strange undefined behavior of a 5 second delay. The fix is to call...

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(receivedData:) withObject:result waitUntilDone:YES];
```

...then put the call to setButtonText in the "receivedData" method.

Golden rule when updating something on a UI is to update in the UI thread.

Obviously if I had posted more code to my question you would've seen this. Sorry about that. Lesson learned at least.

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily need to detect the long press, so much as alter the state in which your selector is fired by the button.  If you're doing this programmatically, you should have something like this:

```
[self.myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(mySelector) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

In a XIB/Storyboard, the option is available in the palette under "Touch Down":

[image]

This causes a selector to be fired immediately at the touch of a button, rather than, what I can assume, you have set to `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`, in which events are sent when touches end in the vicinity of the button.

Comment: While this is a good workaround (possibly the solution?), I'm still curious why there's a 5 second delay before the button text updates.

Comment: @Alphatrak my best guess would be that you're using blocking network operations, which means your UI cannot update before the main thread is unblocked (or, therefore, when your network requests are finished).